# How to generate json schema from kotlin class

Tags: json, kotlin, model, schema, data-class

Is there a way to automatically generate JSON schema or Protobuf schema from Kotlin classes/ data classes?
I have an android project and I wish to be able to use my data model classes in TypeScript and Swift without the need to write them again. As there are converters from JSON schema to almost every programming language I suppose converting Kotlin classes to JSON schema would do the trick.

Comment: What would be the benefit for JavaScript, given that it has no types? Did you mean TypeScript?

Comment: I personally don't know about any such tool, maybe `kotlinx.serialization` does that? But you might also explore another option: define your model classes as a separate multiplatform module that you compile for JVM, JS and Native (for swift).

Comment: @Joffrey yes. I meant TypeScript

Comment: Joffrey is right, `kotlinx.serialization` has examples of doing just that: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/tree/master/examples/example-visitors/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/serialization/schema (see https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/tree/master/examples for the readme). But I'd suggest the more usual workflow of starting with the JSON Schema/Protobuf and generating Kotlin from them.

Comment: Nice little project here which depends on kotlinx.serialization -> https://github.com/Ricky12Awesome/json-schema-serialization

Comment: I had to go digging for this one.. not even sure its valid any more.. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/1fe9ec1d07125c12a196d5a49959c400ea593cdf/examples/example-visitors/src/main/kotlin/App.kt